# Scanning network devices by mac address

Tags: networking, arp

I work in the security devices industry and most of my work relates to IP cameras. Each camera manufacturer has their own software that scans the network for their cameras and gives details about those cameras even if they have no assigned ip address. The problem is that sometimes we go to sites that have cameras from different manufacturers and the people there don't always know what makes they are or even where they are (large sites obviously) so for us trying to reconfigure those cameras gets a bit tricky since you always have to have all the software from different manufacturers with you all the time.

Is there a way that I can scan the network and find the mac and ip (or self assigned ip) addresses even if no ip address is assigned?

Ideally I'd like to know how to do this with Windows, but linux might be ok too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible ways:

1. Download and install NMAP and run. `nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24`. Assuming you IP range is 192.168.0.0.
2. Ping the networks broadcast address, which will get every host to reply, but only if they have a working IP. Then check your ARP tables.
3. If you can get access to the switch. Check MAC address and or forwarding table.
4. If you know the port the camera is connect into, connect that port  into a hub (disconnect from current switch). Also connect a laptop with wireshark running into the same hub that will give you a list of all MACs on that hub, then you can eliminate the laptop and hub MAC.

It might also be useful to get a list together of all possible manufacturers and get the MACs of 2-3  devices you have knowledge of. Make a XLS list and you will notice that MACs from each manufacturer usually have similar characters apart from the last 4. This will help you eliminate non Camera MACs and help identify particular manufacturers.

This tool is a windows application that is similar to the NMAP command in that you can scan and entire IP range for MACs. Again this will only work if the device has a IP range.

http://www.youngzsoft.net/cc-get-mac-address/

Comment: Thanks. The nmap suggestion seems like the most reasonable because as I mentioned I don't always know what cameras are installed and it is not always possible to get easy access to the switches.

Answer (score 1):

Have the network team get you a copy of the arp tables from the switches with a filter by the subnet that the cameras are on.

Cisco command to show IP to mac address use:
show arp | include "regular-expression"

Cisco command to show Mac address without an IP:
show mac-address-table 
(you could filter on mac addresses OUI that you know could be at the site)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to switches to get ARP tables, your last resort can be physical access to the cameras: all cams I've seen had a sticker or other label with serial number and MAC-address, unless someone removed these labels.

Also, if these cameras sending their signal somewhere, there must be a kind of list with their IPs and so on.

Another way: recently I installed onto my android tablet the software "IP cam viewer lite" by Robert Chou. It scans the network for different models of IP-cams, and does that reliable enough.

Knowing the IP-address boundaries of the network in question, you may run nmap tool for ping-scan of this range. And, yes, nmap is available for Windows (ask guys from Spiceworks team)

Comment: So I guess the answer is it is not possible. The whole idea is to be able to do that without having to ask people on site. In most cases they are non-technical people.

Answer (score 0):

This Batch Code will fetch the below Details,

1. PC Name
2. IP Address
3. MAC Address
4. Computer Description(If Available)

Please save the below code in **anyname.bat** format and run it. It will output the results in a separate text file.

```
    :: This Windows Batch(CMD) File fetches All the Details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN (Upto 254 host's).
    :: Windows OS (CMD)
    :: Author : [M.S.Arun][1]

    :: #****************************************************************** Start of Script ********************************************************************#

    @echo off
    title Remote PC Details Fetching Script(PC Name / IP's / Computer Description)
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    echo Remote PC Details Fetching Script (PC Name / IP's / Computer Description) details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN.(Upto 254 Hosts)
    echo.
    set /p input_ip="Please Enter the IP Range(Eg:192.168.1) :  " && echo
    set /p input_ip_start="Please Enter Start IP Range(Eg:1) :  " && echo
    set /p input_ip_end="Please Enter End IP Range(Eg:254) :  " && echo
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    @echo on
    for /l %%i in (%input_ip_start%, 1, %input_ip_end%) do nbtstat -a %input_ip%.%%i | findstr /c:"MAC" /c:"<00>" | findstr /c:"MAC" /c:"UNIQUE" >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt && echo     IP Address  = %input_ip%.%%i >> %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    @echo off
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. > %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo This Batch Script fetches All the Details of the Nearby PC's of Same VLAN.(Starting from 1 to 254 host's) >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC Host Name: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "UNIQUE" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC IP Address: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "IP" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC MAC Address: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    find "MAC" PC_Details_Temp.txt >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo PC Seat No's. and Vnet No's: >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    net view /all >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    echo. >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    arp -a >> %cd%\PC_Details_Logs.txt
    :: del %cd%\PC_Details_Temp.txt
    echo.
    echo Completed Successfully..!
    echo.
    pause

    :: #****************************************************************** End of Script ********************************************************************#
```

Hope this might help.

Screenshots For References

[image]

[image]